# Android6.0 WifiManager.getScanResults()

Tags: java, android, permissions, android-permissions, android-wifi

The size of list is 0, which is the return of **WifiManager.getScanResults() in Android6.0**
I had given the permission(ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION and ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) to him, but the size of list is still 0.
I sure the app has these permission in my phone Setting -> Apps.
Do you know the reson? Any Solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Android 6.0, permission behaviour has changed to runtime

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
   requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                 PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE_ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
    //After this point you wait for callback in onRequestPermissionsResult(int, String[], int[]) overriden method

}else{
    getScanningResults();
   //do something, permission was previously granted; or legacy device
}



@Override
 public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
         int[] grantResults) {
     if (requestCode == PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE_ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
             && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
         // Do something with granted permission
        mWifiListener.getScanningResults();
     }
 }
```

Comment: I had given it the permission, but it is still no effect.

Comment: I don't know why this way is not successful when I have replied, but today  it is suddenly effective. Your answer is correct.

Comment: DNwalter, the answer is correct but you need also to enable the gps on your device in order to obtain the list not empty. And this is a known issue [red here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=185370)